# How can I remove this "" from the character array?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swiftui, chararray

This returned to me as a string:

```
result: vier­hundert­sieben­und­achtzig
```

I cast the string in Array.

```
self.randomNumberText = Array(self.numberConfig.numberString)
print("\(self.randomNumberText)")
["v", "i", "e", "r", "­", "h", "u", "n", "d", "e", "r", "t", "­", "s", "i", "e", "b", "e", "n", "­", "u", "n", "d", "­", "a", "c", "h", "t", "z", "i", "g"]
```

There are quotes("") that are hollow between the words. How can I remove these double quotes("")?
The reason I cast the String in the Array: I check whether each letter entered from the TextField is spelled correctly. However, since there is "" this sign in between, I cannot check whether it is spelled correctly.

**Number Config**

```
class NumberConfig: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var numberString: String = "-"

    @Published var randomNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.numberString = self.numberToText(number: randomNumber)
        }
    }
    
    func numberToText(number: Int) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
        let result = formatter.string(for: number) ?? "-"
        print("result: \(result)")
        return result
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    import Combine
    struct NumberToTextView: View {
        @ObservedObject var numberConfig = NumberConfig()
        @ObservedObject var textBindingManager = TextBindingManager(limit: 1)
        @ObservedObject var speechConfig = SpeechConfig()
        @State var randomNumber: [String.Element] = []
        @State var randomNumberText: [String.Element] = []
        @State var isCorrectAnswer: Bool = false
        @State var isTrueStep: Bool = false
        var body: some View {

....
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        
                        TextField("Sayıyı yazınız", text: $textBindingManager.text)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground))
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                            .onReceive(Just(self.textBindingManager.text), perform: { value in
                                let result = zip(self.randomNumberText, value).map({ $0 == $1 }).reduce(true, {$0 && $1})
                                if result && !self.textBindingManager.text.isEmpty {
                                    self.isTrueStep = true
                                    print("true")
                                    print("valeu: \(value) - \(self.randomNumberText)")
                                } else {
                                    self.isTrueStep = false
                                    print("falsee")
                                }
                            })
                            
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(self.isTrueStep ? .green : .red)
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .padding(5)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
...
        }
    }
```

Comment: The spaces are expected if you read the documentation (and perfectly valid German). But if you don't want them, just substring them away or filter them out of the character array.

Comment: @jnpdx Value of type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') has no member 'isEmpty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the `Character` array is a bit tricky because an empty string isn't actually a character.

Nevertheless there is a way: Filter all ASCII characters

```
self.randomNumberText = Array(self.numberConfig.numberString).filter{$0.isASCII }
```

or filter all `letters`

```
self.randomNumberText = Array(self.numberConfig.numberString).filter{$0.isLetter }
```